# Font.registerFont(). Error #1508: The value specified for argument font is invalid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This is my EnglishFonts.swf application that contains embedded fonts:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class EnglishFonts extends Sprite implements IFontApplication
    {
        [Embed(
            source="../../assets/en/segoeprb.ttf",
            fontName="Segoe Print",
            unicodeRange="U+0048, U+0061, U+0073, U+006E, U+0074, U+003A, U+0030-0039"
        )]
        public var SegoePrintBold:Class;

        public function get fonts():Vector.<Class>
        {
            return Vector.<Class>([SegoePrintBold]);
        }
    }
}
```

In my Flex application, I load this EnglishFonts.swf through the Loader class and try to register the embedded font like this:

```
var fontsApplication:DisplayObject = loader.content;
var fonts:Vector.<Class> = fontsApplication['fonts'] as Vector.<Class>;
Font.registerFont(fonts[0]);
```

Font.registerFont() throws this error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1508: The value specified for argument font is invalid.
    at flash.text::Font$/registerFont()
```

Comment: If you trace() or debug the object referenced by fonts[0], what does it say? What type of object is it? Just to confirm that there is no issue causing it to be anything other than a Class.

Comment: `trace(new fonts[0] is Font)` outputs `true`.

Comment: What does `trace((new fonts[0]).fontName)` say?

Comment: @Laurent `trace(fonts[0], new fonts[0], new fonts[0]().fontName)` outputs `[class EnglishFonts_SegoePrintBold] [object EnglishFonts_SegoePrintBold] Segoe Print`, so I'm pretty sure the correct font is loaded. However, I have absolutely no idea why Font.registerFont() isn't accepting it.

Comment: Did you try without the Unicode ranges? I'm just guessing - maybe these ranges are not all included in the font?

Comment: I just tried opening the compiled application in my browser and it worked fine there but when I press F11 (debug) in Flash Builder, which shows the output in stand-alone Flash Player, I get this run-time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error only occurs when I run my application in stand-alone Flash Player. It runs fine in the browser. I couldn't figure out why this is.

Comment: Are you going to find out the reason, or not?

Comment: This sucks.  It's throwing an error locally... so I'm not going to publish it in a browser and hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is cos of security. If you put your fonts.swf in same directory with loader will loads and you can register fonts without problem. You can register you fonts also inside EnglishFonts constructor. If you use Flash to create fonts.swf Flash automatically add Font.registerFont in constructor of document class.
Securty.allowDomain("*") in fonts.swf wouldn't help but if you create LoaderContext policy file or some settings in your Loader might help.
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Winx is right, problem occurs because of security. Possible fix can be :: add your "bin" folder to trusted locations using this panel :: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

or using system application for flashplayer settings